# Evaluating Complicated Definite Integral Problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

For this problem, I'm pretty lost where to start. I've tried dividing the function up with 5sqrt3x under each part of the numerator, but I get lost on what to do with my algebra. I don't think you would use u substitution, but I'm not sure.

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQDlE.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is more likely to get an answer if you use [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math, include all formulas in the question instead of in a figure, be more precise in what you're asking and show that you have put some effort to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put all of the $x$ radicals into fractional exponent form. You can leave the constants in radicals.

Then, break this into three separate definite integrals by dividing each term in the numerator by $5\sqrt{3x}$, as you initially tried. Remember to slap limits on each integral.

Next, pull the coefficients out of each integral.

Fourthly, use the power rule for integrals:

$$\int x^n \, dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + C$$

Finally, evaluate each of the three terms between $9$ and $0$. It will be messy algebra, but take your time.

[image: integra]

According to my calculator, that is the correct answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, @lk2020 .  I am a calculus student myself, so I understand how difficult it can be to get answers to your questions.  Fair warning though—most people will not answer a bare question like the one you posed today.  Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Also, @lk2020 , I highly recommend the site *Wolfram|Alpha* for any future questions.